# Cannot add design documents (beginning with "_") in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

When I try to add design documents (beginning with "_") I get an error "Only reserved document ids may start with underscore." How can I add a design document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [*Definitive Guide*](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/design.html), a design document like this one:

```
{
  "_id" : "_design/example",
  "views" : {
    "foo" : {
      "map" : "function(doc){ emit(doc._id, doc._rev)}"
    }
  }
}
```

can be added to the database named `basic` with a curl command like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/basic/_design/example --data-binary @mydesign.json
```

Personally, I find it much easier to use [CouchApp](http://couchapp.org/page/index) to add and manage design documents.  [This section](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/managing.html) of the *Definitive Guide* describes how to install and use it.

Comment: Ya I have looked over the Definitive Guide. I am also reading about and beginning to play with it. However, when I try "curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/basic/_design/example --data-binary @mydesign.js" and when I try to add a design document through Futon (in the browser) I get the error '{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Only reserved document ids may start with underscore."}'.

Comment: Funny, I just tried it again and it works fine for me. `curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/g3/_design/example --data-binary @mydesign.json` 
`{"ok":true,"id":"_design/example","rev":"1-230141dfa7e07c3dbfef0789bf11773a"}`  What version of CouchDB are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.2.0 which I believe is the current.

Comment: Yes it is and it is the same version I'm using.  Can you update your question with the design document you're trying to upload?

Comment: I have tried uploading many different JSONs to see if the file to be PUT was the issue. However, I get the same error even when I do "curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/tweetaction/_design/" which I believe is the correct syntax for posting a blank design document.

Comment: I don't believe that is the correct syntax for creating a blank design document.  It doesn't provide an _id for the design document.  When I try it I get the same error.  If you want to create a blank design document you must pvide a full _id and some json.  For example, this works for me to create an empty design document:  `curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/blank --data-binary "{}"`